# format timezone using XSLT/xpath 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need to get one date in one format like this:

2020-06-03T06:14:00.000+0100.

following this documentation page [1], I tried to do with this expression, but always get an error:

format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]-[H01]:[m01]:[s][Z0000]")

I tried to put with this mask too:

format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]-[H01]:[m01]:[s][Z0001]")

but the result is 2020-06-03-14:39:50+02:00

I need to delete the ":" on the offset, ¿Which mask may I use?

[1]https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with Saxon-HE 9.9.1.4J, and the output is `2020-06-03-14:50:35+0200`. So no colon in the last element.

Comment: Ok, then it could be an issue of Tibco BW6, I'll try to contact with they. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for your problem could be splitting the output of `format-dateTime` into two parts and remove the colon on the second expression:

```
concat(format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]-[H01]:[m01]:[s]"),translate(format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Z0001]"),":",""))
```

Maybe this works for you.